# How can I stream paginated data (with Entity Framework) from a database to Amazon S3 while avoiding memory overflow?

Tags: amazon-s3

We have a process running on .net Core 7 that needs to read information from a database and write csv to s3. The limitation is that the database could have millions of rows and fetching/writing all the information at once would cause a memory overflow. I know how to paginate this approach on the DB side using skip and take to process in batches with Entity Framework, but what I have not been able to discover is how to stream this to S3 as I am processing it. I do not want to create the file locally and then upload, but rather to stream right to S3 if possible as I am processing each page of database records.

Thanks in Advance for any help.

I have tried TransferUtility, PutObjectAsync, etc. but no matter what I try to do, I end up with "Stream was not writeable." error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: we decided the best way forward was just to create the file locally and then put it to s3 all at once, then cleanup locally when done. Since it's ephemeral storage, won't matter for long-term anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We decided that rather than try to 'stream' to s3, we would instead create the file locally and then put to s3 all at once. This works for our needs as it seems there is no way to do what I am asking with S3.